# Rails update one models attribute from different models create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model that has many customers.  The user model has an integer attribute eft_percent, and the customer has a boolean attribute eft.  I need the users eft_percent attribute to update when a customer for this user is created.  Here is my code right now:

```
after_action :calculate_eft, only: [:create]

def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  if @customer.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Customer created'
    redirect_to customers_url
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Error creating customer'
    redirect_to new_customer_url
  end
end

private

def calculate_eft
  @user = User.find(@customer.user_id)
  @user.eft_percent = @user.customers.where(eft: true).count * 100 / @user.customers.count
  @user.save
end
```

When I create a customer the users eft_percent attribute is not changed.  All help is appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't you call @user.save as the last line in calculate_eft to persist the new value into database?

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work (I think I mentioned that in the post).  I am wondering if I need to do update_attributes or something.

Comment: Do you get corect results if you print the value from: '@user.customers.where(eft: true).count * 100 / @user.customers.count' ?

Comment: I changed the post to reflect @user.save.  Again, it is not working.  The users eft_percent is not changed.

Comment: Yes, I can just put the code in the users show view and it works, however I have a bunch of attributes that I need to do the same thing with and so I need to just make them user attributes so I don't have to calculate all of that every time the view is loaded.  If the calculations are done when a customer is created it saves the time of having to do it on the fly when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot more like a controller than a model. So, this is a model behaviour and as such, it should be in the model:

customer.rb:

```
belongs_to :user

after_create {
    newval = user.customers.where(eft: true).count * 100 / user.customers.count
    user.update_attribute(:eft_percent, newval)
end
```

To update more attributes, just pass a hash.  Careful not to confuse user and customer. The hash should contain only user attributes

```
user.update_attributes({attr1: val1, attr2: val2})
```

or

```
user.update_columns({attr1: val1, attr2: val2})
```

Comment: I need to only update the user for which this customer belongs to, with this code it does not define which user gets updated right?  How would I update the specific users attribute that the customer belongs to?

Comment: `user` is a shorthand for `current_object.user` (`self.user`), since model `belongs_to :user`. It will only update the user which the customer belongs to.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Handling your associations correctly can save you a lot of work.

Comment: One more question: how would i do the update attributes for multiple attributes in your example?  Just do user.update_attributes(:eft_percent, eft_val, :other_stat, other_val) or would I put them in a hash, or what would be the best method to do this on multiple attributes?

Comment: I tried the method I mentioned and I tried the hash, neither worked.  Right now I am just duplicating your code for each attribute, but there has to be a cleaner way.

Comment: For some reason, doing this, updating attributes from the customer controller using that code, clears my users password every time, it just sets the users password to blank.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'd have to see the users model